# Why CLR does not check a hash values of netmodules linked into the strongly named dll

Tags: c#, .net, dll, hash

Why CLR does not check a hash values of netmodules linked into the strongly named dll?

Now the whole story..

There are two independent C# source files simple.cs and complex.cs which are compiled into two netmodules

```
csc /target:module complex.cs
csc /target:module simple.cs
```

which are then linked into the strongly named math.dll

```
al /target:library /keyfile:keyfile.snk /out:math.dll /version:0.0.0.0 
complex.netmodule simple.netmodule
```

keyfile.snk has been created earlier by running:

```
sn /k keyfile.snk
```

Checked manifest of math.dll for the hash values corresponding to complex.netmodule and simple.netmodule:

```
.file complex.netmodule
.hash = (D2 B4 1D 11 B1 50 C2 29 01 91 49 10 2C 28 91 45   // .....P.)..I.,(.E
         24 44 A3 B5 )                                     // $D..
.file simple.netmodule
.hash = (29 85 33 28 35 94 03 32 68 E4 30 B6 02 42 B2 8F   // ).3(5..2h.0..B..
         E8 0B A8 8F )
```

Building client exe :

```
csc /target:exe /reference:math.dll mathclient.cs
```

Running mathclient.exe and the output:

2+2=4
3 squared=9

Then modified complex.cs and recompiled. Here I understand that a hash value of the complex.netmodule shall be changed.

Run mathclient again and expect that an exception  is thrown since hash value of new complex.netmodule does not match the one from math.dll manifest. However the result is

2+2=2
3 squared=10

So, new version of the complex.netmodule was used.

Any idea why CLR did not perform a hash validation for included netmodules?

Comment: "Here I understand that a hash value of the complex.netmodule shall be changed." - did you actually check to see if the hash *was different*?

Comment: Am i missing something or, when you 'modified and recompiled', the new hash values where calculated for the latest versions of your modules and put into the new assembly, right? When running the same hashing against the content of the assembly, it would yield the value as put into the manifest? If you would try a binary replace of the content of the module without re-linking, it should fail.

Comment: And as for checking the math.dll assembly, thats done on a assembly scope, which is generated during signing of the assembly. Your math.exe will pick up math.dll if it's FQN is correct and the assembly load signature verification succeeds. (or you have verification skipping turned on for that asseembly/keytoken)

Comment: Is your assembly running in a full trust context?  If so, strong name validation is likely being bypassed for performance reasons.  Try disabling the bypassing by following [these instructions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc713694.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

For performance reasons.  It would take too long to load the app if it had to calculate the hash of all the binaries.